# Is it possible to change the screen resolution within a Swing JFrame

Tags: swing, javafx

I would like to be able to change the resolution of the screen, just inside a JFrame, so that I can for example magnify animations by hovering the frame over the animation, similar to the Windows Screen Magnifier.

It is not sufficient to just capture that portion of the screen into an image and then scale it, because that would not work with animations.

If it is not possible in Swing, then JavaFX would be another alternative

Comment: So, you're trying to make a magnifying glass style program?  I'd say no, not natively, you'd have to investigate using a JNI/JNA based solution

Comment: @MadProgrammer: I'm thinking he can animate off-screen and use one of your [spotlight](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A992484+spotlight) examples.

Comment: @trashgod I don't know what this "animation" is, is it video via something like vlcj

Comment: @trashgod I'm just not sure what the OP is actually asking or what they are trying to do so it's impossible to provide any kind of reasonable answer :P

Answer (score -1):

If it's a full screen app , set DisplayMode. For window app, you can try search JavaFX DPI Scaling.